# How to update on node js using sqlite3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I would like to ask how to update on sqlite3 node js, the first function is working (views the data in the HTML from the database), my problem is how to update it. Thanks!

```js
exports.post = function(req, res){

var id = JSON.stringify(req.body.id);

var inputData = [req.body.GIVENNAME, req.body.SURNAME, id];


db.run("UPDATE f11 SET GIVENNAME=$GIVENNAME, SURNAME=? WHERE id=?",inputData,
{
 $GIVENNAME : GIVENNAME,
 $SURNAME : SURNAME,

 
  });

 res.redirect("/legone/survey/surveyform/form11");
 
};
```

Comment: what all fields you want to update. Also, please post your f11 table structure. You can edit the question and add the table structure.

Comment: var data = {
            
           name       : input.name,
     address        : input.address,
     latitude    : input.latitude,
     longtitude  : input.longtitude,
     importantL  : input.importantL,
     contactP   : input.contactP,
     contactN   : input.contactN,
     comment   : input.comment,
     foodStore1  : input.foodStore1,
     foodStore2  : input.foodStore2,
     foodID   : input.foodID,
     chain   : input.chain,
     cashReg   : input.cashReg,
     manning   : input.manning,
     daysOpen   : input.daysOpen,

        
        };

Comment: how do i pass the array to db.run("UPDATE table_name where condition");

Comment: you want to set the values of the columns as defined in the first comment?

Comment: Yes sir. the correct query code for "UPDATE"

Answer (score 1):

Update :

You can try running your query like this:

```
var inputData = [req.body.GIVENNAME, req.body.SURNAME, id];

db.run("UPDATE f11 SET GIVENNAME=?, SURNAME=? WHERE id=?",inputData,function(err,rows){
    ....
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it doesnt update, i have edited my code. can you tell what is the correct code for that. sorry im just a beginner in  programming